# creating a virtual environment and file part onvscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

pipenv install django is not creating a virtual environment for me ,i am trying to create a virtual environment via my cmd on my windows , with the command "pipenv intall django", it install django but dont create the enironment ,  what should i do? and my file part seem not to be working

pipenv intall django was supposed to download django and create an environment but it didnt ..... and copying and pasting a file part on my vscode it says invalid interpreter ....commmand used was "pipenv --venv..." got the file part and append bin\python but it didnt work

Comment: "seems not to work" and "didn't work" are not a clear description of the problem. Installation of pipenv documentation is here: [preferred-installation-of-pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html#preferred-installation-of-pipenv) - Pay attention to windows specific instructions if you are on windows, etc. Installing packages with pipenv is here: [installing-packages-for-your-project](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-packages-for-your-project) I have not used pipenv with vscode but make sure you open the project folder when working in the project.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is not to use pipenv. I recommend you to start creating the virtual environment first and then install Django.

In VSCode, press Ctrl P and then type in ">" to enable the command
palete.

After that you see something like this:

[image]

Type or press "Python: Create Environment"

Chooses the first option "venv" (the default one):
[image]

Then chooses your suitable Python version (if you have different version exists on your machine).

Next, all you have to do is open the command line. There should be a "(.venv)" in the beginning of the line in your cmd (meaning the virtual environment is activated):

[image]

Finally, you can just install Django via pip:

```
pip install django
```

Then Django should be installed properly into your virtual environment.

In case there is any problem with activating the virtual environment, read
[here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3239675/virtualenv-and-venv-python-virtual-environments-explained.html) for more specific solution.